Solving $1+2\sum_{\sigma=1}^{(M-1)/2}\cos^2{\left(\frac{M\pi\sigma}{M+1}\right)}\cos{(\sigma\gamma)} = 0 $, with $M$ odd, for $\gamma$
Consider the following trigonometric equations in the variable $\gamma$ (with $0\leq \gamma \leq \pi$) depending on the positive integer $M>1$.
If $M$ is odd, the equation is
$$
1 + 2\sum_{\sigma = 1}^{\frac{M-1}{2}} \cos^2{\left(\frac{M\pi\sigma}{M+1}\right)} \cos{(\sigma \gamma)} = 0 \tag1
$$
If $M$ is even, the equation is
$$
\sum_{\sigma = 1,3,5...}^{M-1} \sin^2{\left(\frac{\pi M \sigma}{2(M+1)}\right)} \cos{\left(\sigma\frac{\gamma}{2}\right)} = 0 \tag2
$$
Notice that in the former sum the index $\sigma$ takes all the integer values, while in the latter it only takes odd values.
Besides the trivial solution $\gamma = \pi$, I am not able to find the other solutions with analytic approaches.
However, with the help of Mathematica I have verified that, up to $M$ as large as $80$ the solutions take the simple form $\gamma = 2(2+k)\pi/(M+1)$, where $k = 0, ... \lfloor (M-3)/2 \rfloor$, but I am not able to prove it exactly.
Is it possible to prove that these are indeed all the solutions?
Thank you for any help! :)
